# Django: How to set a hidden field on a generic create view?

Tags: django, django-generic-views

I'm running Django 1.6.x

To extend my user I've added another model storing the data:

```
class UserProfile (models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    height = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Now I wand to add a view, which is allowing the user to add its own infos there. Started with `django.views.generic.edit.CreateView`, but want also to provide at least the edit/update one to.

So I've added the import and created a view:

```
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView, UpdateView
# .... 
class UserProfileCreateView(CreateView):
    model = UserProfile
    fields = ['height']
```

Also I've added the entry inside urls.py:

```
    url(r'^userprofile/new/$', login_required(UserProfileCreateView.as_view()), name="add_userprofile")
```

But now I'm stuck on the point how to assign the user ID in the correct way. I want to have this field set in background. Any hints?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can do it that way:

- get user from request object.
- overwrite form_valid method on your UserProfileCreateView class,
- attach user to form instance and save it.

```
class UserProfileCreateView(CreateView):
    model = UserProfile
    fields = ['height']

     def form_valid(self, form):
         user = self.request.user
         form.instance.user = user
         return super(UserProfileCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

This code is for Python 2.7.x

Comment: 2 years later, still a great answer!

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Because those fields are not filled, it never validates as true and so the code never runs :(

Comment: 4 years later, still useful

Comment: 5 years later, still useful

Answer (score 2):

```
class UserProfileCreateView(CreateView):
    def form_valid(self, form):
         self.object = form.save(commit=False)
         self.object.user = self.request.user
         self.object.save()
         return super(ModelFormMixin, self).form_valid(form)
```

Comment: Wouldn't this save the object even if it is not valid?

Comment: this method call after validation in ProcessFormView,

Comment: Ah right. I'm not too used with the class based views. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid gottcha's like  **must be a “User” instance** error  you would want to try this.

```
 def form_valid(self, form):
        owner = self.request.user
        print("Bot owner1", owner)
        tenant = get_object_or_404(Tenant, user=owner)
        print("Bot owner2 ", tenant)
        form.instance.tenant = tenant

    return super().form_valid(form)
```

Turned out that

```
print("Bot owner1", owner)
```

and

```
print("Bot owner2 ", tenant)
```

have different results.

Any other approach besides the `form_valid` method could pose a security risk.
i.e I could edit the initial value by inspecting element on your browser and put my new value. If your code does not validate my entry Bang!!!Bang!! you're hacked.