# Is any way to create hidden form field in CreateView form?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Is any way to create hidden form field in CreateView form?

```
class CommentAdd(AjaxableResponseMixin, CreateView):
    model = Comment
    fields = ['author_name', 'text']
    success_url = '/thanks/'
    template_name = 'tree.html'
```

I have to pass some data (parent of comment) to the database. It works good with ModelForm, I pass parent with JS to the hidden field:

```
widgets = {'parent': widgets.HiddenInput}
```

How to do the same with CreateView form?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django: How to set a hidden field on a generic create view?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21652073/django-how-to-set-a-hidden-field-on-a-generic-create-view)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a model form class that includes the hidden input.

```
class CommentForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ('author_name', 'text', 'parent')
        widgets = {
            'parent': forms.HiddenInput,
        }
```

Then use that form in your view using the `form_class` attribute.

```
class CommentAdd(AjaxableResponseMixin, CreateView):
    form_class = CommentForm
    ...
```