# How to pass user object to a Modelform using CreateView

Tags: django, django-class-based-views, modelform

**NOT NULL constraint failed: blog_post.author_id**

Hi, I'm fairly new to django and can't fix this error.

I'm building a blog app and I want the author to be the current user.
I know that I'm not passing the user object to the form properly, but none of the solutions I found worked for me.

Thank you in advance!

**models.py**

```
class User(auth.models.User,auth.models.PermissionsMixin):
    def __str__(self):
        return '@{}'.format(self.username)


class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('post_detail',kwargs={'pk':self.pk})
```

**forms.py**

```
class UserForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2')
        model = get_user_model()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)


 class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
     class Meta:
         model = Post
         fields = ('title', 'text',)
```

**views.py**

```
class SignUpView(CreateView):
    form_class = UserForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('login')
    template_name = 'registration/signup.html'

class PostCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    login_url = '/login/'
    redirect_field_name = 'blog/post_detail.html'

    form_class = PostForm
    model = Post
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django: How to set a hidden field on a generic create view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21652073/django-how-to-set-a-hidden-field-on-a-generic-create-view)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution that worked in my case and is pretty similar to yours @Silas.

**views.py**

```
class PostCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    login_url = '/login/'
    redirect_field_name = 'blog/post_detail.html'
    form_class = PostForm
    model = Post

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.author = self.request.user
        self.object.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

**models.py**

```
class Post(models.Model):
author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is good except that you are not passing User object to update author field.

I think in your PostCreateView, you can do something like this:

```
class PostCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
     login_url = '/login/'
     redirect_field_name = 'blog/post_detail.html'
     form_class = PostForm
     model = Post

     def valid_form(self,form, **kwargs):
         form.instance.author = self.request.user
         super(PosetCreateView, self).get_context_data(kwargs)

         return HttpResponse('/')
```

Comment: Makes sense but doesn't solve it thank you tho!  I guess I'll switch to function views, this way I at least know what is going on under the hood.